# to_json not working with selectExpr in spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I am reading a databricks blog [link](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/complex-nested-structured.html)
and I find a problem with the built-in function `to_json`.
In the codes blew within this tutorial, it returns error:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'to_json'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.

Does this means that this usage in the tutorial is wrong? and no udf could be used in `selectExpr`. Could I do something like register this `to_json` function into default database?

```
val deviceAlertQuery = notifydevicesDS
                       .selectExpr("CAST(dcId AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(*)) AS value")
                       .writeStream
                       .format("kafka")
                       .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
                       .option("toipic", "device_alerts")
                       .start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on information I get from mail list. this function are not added into SQL from spark 2.2.0. Here is the commit link:[commit](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/0cdcf9114527a2c359c25e46fd6556b3855bfb28).
Hope this will help. THX Hyukjin Kwon and Burak Yavuz.

Answer (score 2):

You need to improt the `to_json` function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_json
```

This should work rather than the `selectExpr`

```
data.withColumn("key", $"dcId".cast("string"))
  .select(to_json(struct(data.columns.head, data.columns.tail:_*)).as("value")).show()
```

You must also use the **spark 2.x**

I hope this helps to solve your problem.

Comment: are you trying to change all column to json as one column and write it ??

Comment: Updated the answer :)

Comment: actually, I just tried to follow the tutorial in the link. I did import the to_json function. But I found it only work in select but not in selectExpr as described. That's wired. So I hope to find whether only the standard sql function could be used in selectExpr

Comment: I am sot sure about using the function to_json in selectExpr